# gcc:how to remove undefined symbol that is not used?

Tags: gcc

here is some C++ test code:

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) void foo()
{
   int fd = fopen("data1", "rb");
   printf ("%d", fd);
}
```

And all other code don't call function 'foo' and function 'fopen'

Then I use gcc option -ffunction-sections to compile the code to a so file.

As I think, the function foo symbol and foo binary code has't inlcuded in the so file.

But The problem is, I think the symbol 'fopen' should not be symbol table.
ps:I can make sure that only function 'foo' has use 'fopen'.
And it actually is not, when I use command nm, I found 'U' type symbol of 'fopen'.

How is the gcc work?
And has gcc other compile option to found that, symbol 'fopen' is not use, and remove 'fopen' symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the compiler does not know, wheter the symbols are used later.

You can tell at compile time that you gave him the whole program, so that if your program isnt calling the function, nobody would.

The compiling option is `-fwhole-program`.

Comment: when I add option -fwhole-program, nearly all symbols have been removed.

Comment: when I add option -fwhole-program, nearly all symbols have been removed. Actually I just want to remove the unused symbol, and stay the used symbol. How can I tell the compiler? I think that a smart compiler could count the symbol. If the symbol'count is 0, the symbol will be removed.

Comment: He can only remove them because they are not used. If he would remove them while they are still being used, you program would not run.

Comment: Yes, my so can't run  in my program. Did I make a mistake? I only add the option to my so

Comment: You can use that, of course only when it is indeed your whole program. So when it is just going to be a single object file of a bunch, you have to compile all your c files together in one big commandline. Alternatively you could use the link-time-optimizations (`-flto` and others, see man page for more details on them).

Comment: I think the     -flto should be what I want. But I using gcc4.4， and the     -flto is imported in gcc4.5. Next, I will find a gcc4.5 to test the problem.